# Why is there a <quantum-computer> tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Really, that tag should be gotten rid of.

At least, it should be renamed. Why would anyone not choose a tag named "Quantum Computer" in "Quantum Computing" forum?

Comment: Really, people should just read the tag usage :P. But seriously, it is good that you ask before killing the tag.

Answer (score 8):

Looking at the description of the [quantum-computer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quantum-computer) tag, it's currently described as:

> For questions about computers that run on a quantum architecture; the machines themselves, not just any computing that could take place on one.

Personally, I find this a reasonable start and think that questions tagged [quantum-computer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quantum-computer) should be about either the physical or hypothetical *machine* that is called a quantum computer<sup>1</sup>. That is, just because a question is about qubits, noise or simulating a quantum computer<sup>2</sup> does *not* mean it should also have the [quantum-computer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quantum-computer) tag as well, unless relating to an actual, physical (or hypothetical) machine that we could call a quantum computer.

To give a couple of examples, the question [Why must quantum computers be kept near absolute zero?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/105/23) is asking why a physical-machine-that-can-perform-arbitrary-quantum-computations must be kept near absolute zero, so is suited for the tag, while asking [What is the difference between qubit and normal bits?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/112/23) doesn't appear to have anything to do with a physical or hypothetical machine in the same way that talking about a (classical) bit is not the same as talking about a (classical) computer.

However, as just shown, current questions on said tag don't always match this, so some re-tagging would need to be done...

---

<sup>1 Technically, this says nothing about whether the machine is *universal* or not, so we might want to think about tags for (non-)universal quantum computers</sup>

<sup>2 Simulating a QC might be a grey area, to be fair, although there is already a [simulation](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/simulation) tag</sup>

Comment: @Blue the emulation tag should be used when replicating something *exactly* (or as exactly as possible anyway), while simulation is for replicating certain features of a system and is *not* emulation (although at first glance, I'm admittedly not sure if this is represented by the actual questions or not. It's early days yet though)

Comment: Perhaps we should rename it to [tag:quantum-computer-construction] or something that clarifies we're talking about physical stuff here. Would be a nice contrast with the theory tag: [tag:quantum-computing-models]

Comment: @Discretelizard to me, this is all implied by the use of '-er' meaning it's a physical thing, unlike '-ing', but your idea would make things clearer...

Comment: Note that '-er' can also refer to people, as 'computer' has been in the recent past