# Biweekly chat sessions: Timings

Tags: discussion, chat

Having discussed with [@Mithrandir24601](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/users/23/mithrandir24601) and [@agaitaarino](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/users/1847/agaitaarino), I would like to set up a regular chat session in [The Classical Channel](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74398/the-classical-channel), which would be held every alternate week for around 1 hour. Once it is set up, I will update the link to opt-in, here. That is, you will be given the option to opt-in to get email reminders for the chat session every alternate week (a few hours before the chat session begins). Apart from that, you will get the notification message on the site itself, too (as a normal notification).

> The agenda of the chat sessions would be (roughly):
>
> - Introducing new users to the existing community, and answering any questions they might have about the site.
> - Discussing recent research progress in topics related to quantum computing and quantum information.
> - Discussing any problematic issues faced by the members and/or possible ways to improve our site in general.

I feel that such a regular chat session would be helpful in the long run to bring in more traffic, build a closely-knit community and might also help to bring in more subject experts. If this goes well, we might also gradually begin "Ask Me Anything (AMA)" sessions where we could invite experts as guests (probably we would merge the AMA and chat sessions then).

This thread is for gathering all your responses about the session timings which you think will be suitable for you. Please frame your responses in form of answers, below. We will try to choose something which will suit the majority of responders.

**Sample Format:**

> Mon (6 pm - 7 pm / 8 pm - 9 pm), Wed (7 pm - 8 pm), Sat (2 pm - 3 pm / 6 pm - 7 pm)
>
> All timings are in UTC.

P.S: It's better if you *directly* suggest the timing which you think will be best for holding a session, rather than writing out a list of all your free-time hours.

Comment: Hi, I would also like to link to this related post: https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175/how-to-remove-a-tag-retag

Comment: **Note to all moderators:** You can schedule events in the chat rooms. If a mod does this, the event shall be publicly visible in the community bulletin and users can register themselves for this event.

Answer (score 2):

Best for me would be

> Weekdays 5 pm-9 pm (UTC)

Earlier may be possible, later would not be.

Comment: Thanks. That's UTC timings, right?

Comment: Aye, that it be.

Answer (score 2):

Best for me would be

> 9pm to 10pm or 12am to 1am on Monday, Wednesday, or Friday, or anytime on the weekends - maybe 5pm to 6pm? (all times UTC)

For holding a session, I think a weekend time would probably be best.

Comment: The potential issue I see with weekend times is that we tend to get a bit less activity around then, so may not be so good in that fewer people would be interested, or may be good in that it brings more people in when we get less activity

Comment: I don't know if we have enough statistics to determine more or less statistics on certain days, but the weekend of April 21st+22nd were 7+5 questions, from like 7 different people in total.

Answer (score 1):

Best 1h slots for me would be either

> Mon-Sun 5am-6am

or

> Weekdays 2pm-3pm

Doable (and wider) windows would be either

> Mon-Sun 4:30am-6:30am

or

> Weekdays 2pm-6pm

All times in UTC.