# Vive la Quantum (chat sessions)!

Tags: discussion, chat

After the [discussion about times for a biweekly chat session](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/230/23), there is now an addition to [the Classical Channel's schedule](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/74398/the-classical-channel?tab=schedule): Starting next Tuesday ($5^{th}$ June), there will be a biweekly chat session lasting an hour at 6pm (18:00) UTC<sup>1</sup>.

Anyone wishing to <strike>stand with me and</strike> join the <strike>revolution</strike> <strike>crusade</strike> chat sessions is advised to register in order to get notifications before they occur.

---

<sup>1 For those who don't like converting between time zones in their heads, the schedule automatically tells you the right time.</sup>

<sup>Note/disclaimer: I'm not suggesting an actual revolution, only I couldn't resist suggesting that name. If anyone has any objections, I'm happy to get the name changed. For context, this is a reference to the so-called [quantum revolutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_technology#The_first_and_second_quantum_revolutions).</sup>

Comment: The first chat session was successful :) [I've bookmarked it](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74398/conversation/chat-session-06-06-2018) if anyone wants to read through it